# MySQL Operator - Readiness probe failed

Tags: mysql, database, kubernetes, innodb, amazon-eks

I have tries to install the MySQL operator on the Kubernetes cluster using Helm chart, for that, i have followed the step from this official document.
Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-operator/en/mysql-operator-installation-helm.html

After I have checked the deployment

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k get deploy
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
mysql-operator   0/1     1            0           7s
```

The deployment is not ready, so i check the Pods.

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k get po
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-operator-98d6fc64b-tshwk   0/1     Running   0          66s
```

So i use `describe` command to see the events.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  100s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned mysql-op/mysql-operator-98d6fc64b-tshwk to ip-192-168-38-172.us-west-2.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled     100s                kubelet            Container image "container-registry.oracle.com/mysql/community-operator:8.3.0-2.1.2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    100s                kubelet            Created container mysql-operator
  Normal   Started    100s                kubelet            Started container mysql-operator
  Warning  Unhealthy  40s (x22 over 99s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/mysql-operator-ready: No such file or directory
```

So i just manually add the `/tmp/mysql-operator-ready` dir on the operator Pod.

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k exec -it mysql-operator-98d6fc64b-tshwk -- sh
sh-4.4$ touch /tmp/mysql-operator-ready
sh-4.4$ exit
exit
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k get po
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-operator-98d6fc64b-tshwk   1/1     Running   0          4m33s
```

Here, it is showing it is ready, but when i describe the Pod, i am facing the same issue.

`Warning  Unhealthy  4m40s (x22 over 5m39s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/mysql-operator-ready: No such file or directory`

Also, if i deploy the InnoDB Cluster, using this command.

```
helm install mycluster mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster \
    --set credentials.root.user='root' \
    --set credentials.root.password='sakila' \
    --set credentials.root.host='%' \
    --set serverInstances=3 \
    --set routerInstances=1 \
    --set tls.useSelfSigned=true
```

The InnoDB cluster not become online.

```
arun@ArunLAL555:~$ k get innodbcluster
NAME        STATUS   ONLINE   INSTANCES   ROUTERS   AGE
mycluster                     3           1         103s
```